# 'also ... even' vs, 'even ... also'

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions

> 1. In the entire history of English not one native speaker has produced "91 view", so while I am closing this as a duplicate, which it is, it really ***also*** is general reference and ***even*** common knowledge, and as such way too basic for this site.
> 2. In the entire history of English not one native speaker has produced "91 view", so while I am closing this as a duplicate, which it is, it really ***even*** is general reference and ***also*** common knowledge, and as such way too basic for this site.

What, if any, is the difference in meaning between 'also' and 'even' in (1)? Is (2), in which 'also' and 'even' have been interchanged, grammatical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case *even* means approximately ‘what is more, moreover’.

*Even* doesn’t fit well in the first part of the clause, where *really* implies ‘in contrast to’ the previous clause, while *even* implies ‘to a greater degree’—the two adverbs seem to contradict each other. It **does** fit well in the second part, where it lifts *general reference* to the even higher level of *common knowledge*.

The sequence may be paraphrased

> I am closing this as “Duplicate”, which it is
>   BUT
>   it is actually “General Reference”, too—
>   AND NOT JUST
>   ordinary “General Reference”
>   BUT
>   “Common Knowledge”,
>   a fact so widely known that any native speaker could be your reference.

Comment: I don't know of any situation where *[even](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/even)* means “what is more, moreover” and it certainly doesn't have such a meaning in the example. -1.

Comment: @jwpat7 What do you take *even* to mean in *general reference and even common knowledge*?

Comment: @jwpat7 [American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=even&submit.x=48&submit.y=22) **even**, *adv.* **1.b** Indeed; moreover. Used as an intensive.

Comment: (a) “it is general reference and even common knowledge” ↔ “it is general reference and some people think it is common knowledge” (ie *even* = possibility, not certainty, here). (b) AHD's definition appears to support your point of view, although I don't agree that that def applies here.  Note, neither of AHD's examples is a convincing example of such usage.  *Even* doesn't carry a sense of *indeed* or *moreover* in either AHD example. (c) Since my comments reflect opinion rather than real evidence, I won't say more, but if you happen to have a convincing reference, please post.

Comment: “… if you had seen what I have seen of heresy, you would not think it a light thing even in its most apparently harmless and even lovable and pious origins” — *Shaw*.  “The ability to consider, or even to prefer, the interests of others to our own … “— *Niebuhr*  “The whole purpose of the Buddhist was to put back the clock, or even to stop the clock, or even to smash the clock”— *Chesterton*